# disable button validation in asp.net core razorpage for specific button

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a form in razor page with 2 button.

```
 <form method="post" class="form-group ">
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input asp-for="DoctorViewModel.NationalCode" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="10" required onblur="">
    <div class="input-group-append">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-primary " asp-page-handler="GetInfo" >search</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <span asp-validation-for="DoctorViewModel.NationalCode"></span>
 </div>

 .
 .
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label asp-for="DoctorViewModel.Name" class="col-form-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="DoctorViewModel.Name" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="50" required>
      <span asp-validation-for="DoctorViewModel.Name"></span>
 </div>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
 </form>
```

and when click on search button i wants to load form info from a handler.

but when click this button get validation error.
How i can disable validation check for only search button. in asp.net form i used CauseValidation=false.

Answer (score 8):

To skip validation while still using a submit-button, you can try to add the attribute `formnovalidate` :

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" formnovalidate asp-page-handler="GetInfo">search</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The default type for a button is to submit the form it is contained within in most browsers.

You simply need to add a type of button and this should stop the submit and therefore the automatic validation will not trigger.

`<button class="btn btn-outline-primary " type="button" asp-page-handler="GetInfo" >search</button>`